# Formatting subtotals in a matrix report

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, formatting, visual-studio-2005, subtotal

So I have a matrix report where the formatting from my data cells is not inherited by the subtotals.  I read this article (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/d4d21769-2cb0-4bb1-b74b-89e4d31fb724) and it seems I need to remove formatting of the subtotals themselves and add the formatting to the data cells (i.e. inscope(row_rowgroup1) and such types of formulas).

I've never used inscope before so I thought I was bothcing up the syntax.  As such, I tried entering the following for one of my data cells and it still doesn't come in as bold like I'd expect.

=IIF(1=1,"Bold","Normal")

I'm adding this to the fontweight condition on the data cell, so it should be bold, right?  I'm really struggling to see why this would bold this data cell (I'm thinking it should bold the individual rows and subtotals but literally nothing is bold).

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  It was working, but no displaying properly in preview mode.  Once deployed the functionality was as desired.  Sheesh.